# Unable to change owner and group of Nginx error_log and access_log

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-20.04, http-server

Unable to change owner and group of Nginx error_log and access_log

I want to change the owner and group of nginx's error_log and access_log straight away from nginx (not manually using chgrp and chown). While keeping nginx running as root so that it can listen on port 80, 443, and so on.....

Server is running Ubuntu 20.04, nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

It seems like no matter what the location are :

```
/var/www/error_log
/var/www/access_log
/var/www/sub.domain.com/error_log
/var/www/sub.domain.com/access_log
/var/www/sub2.domain.com/error_log
/var/www/sub2.domain.com/access_log
...
```

They are all is owned by `root:root` ignoring settings that is described in the [user](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#user) directive.

Output of `ls -l` :

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  0 Sep 14 09:07 access_log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  0 Sep 14 08:43 error_log
```

Few (Truncated) contents of `/etc/group` :

```
root:x:0:
daemon:x:1:
bin:x:2:
sys:x:3:
adm:x:4:syslog
tty:x:5:syslog
disk:x:6:
lp:x:7:
www-data:x:33:
backup:x:34:
operator:x:37:
...
webservergroup:x:1001:tirtagt,www-data,anotheruserhere
...
```

Even though I had specify the [user](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#user) directive on `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` :

```
user www-data webservergroup;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
```

Example Server block :

```
server {
        listen 80;

        root /var/www/sub.example.com;

        # Set the domain name or server name here
        server_name sub.example.com;

        # error_log
        error_log /var/www/sub.example.com/error_log notice;
        access_log /var/www/sub.example.com/access_log;
    
        # Declare a priority if there is no path or files specified.
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        # Catch All Location
        location / {
                # Pass it to the FastCGI PHP bridge
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;

                # Run the DynamicPHPRouter for anything and let it do it's job.
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/srouter.php;
        }
}
```

Expected behaviour would be that the `error_log` and `access_log` is created as www-data as the owner, and webservergroup as the group, something like this when we run `ls -l` :

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data webservergroup  0 Sep 14 09:07 access_log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data webservergroup  0 Sep 14 08:43 error_log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any other way, for now....

I just let Nginx create the file which will be owned by `root`, and then manually do `chgrp` and `chown` to my target user after the file was created.

For me, I use `webservergroup` as the the file group, which nginx is also running on, so the log file is read and write-able.